# libxml2 Copy node without namespace or replace/remove namespace

Tags: xml, libxml2

I have some xml like

```
<node xmlns="path/to/namespace">
  <grammar prop1="bla-bla-bla" prop2="etc">
    <!-- ... -->
  </grammar>
</node>
```

and I want to get grammar-tag, set my namespace and save all properties(prop1, prop2), children nodes and so on.
I just move to grammar-tag and call `xmlNodePtr copied = xmlCopyNode(node, 1);`.
After that I remove some properties, add new and so on(in copied).
After that I want to replace namespace `"/path/to/namespace"` to `"/path/to/namespace2"`.
There is no function like `xmlRemoveNs` or `xmlReplaceNs`, so I just free namespace and set new.

```
if (copied->ns)
{
  xmlFree((void*)copied->ns->href);
  copied->ns->href = xmlStrdup((const xmlChar *)"/path/to/namespace2");
}
```

but it looks weird and a little awful.
Is there way to replace namespace, copy without namespace or delete namespace and set new?

Answer (score 2):

The function `xmlFree()` only free the memory allocated by some library function and that is not what are you searching for.

Try to use for example `xmlSetNsProp()`:

```
xmlAttrPtr xmlSetNsProp(xmlNodePtr node, xmlNsPtr ns, const xmlChar * name, const xmlChar * value)
```

> Set (or reset) an attribute carried by a node. The ns structure must be in scope, this is not checked
>
> node:  the node
>
> ns:    the namespace definition
>
> name:  the attribute name
>
> value: the attribute value
>
> Returns:   the attribute pointer.

You will find more information here: http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html
and I think you can find the function that best suits your needs.

In the source code it seems that the namespace is intended as `ns->href` :

```
/**
 * xmlSetNsProp:
 * @node:  the node
 * @ns:  the namespace definition
 * @name:  the attribute name
 * @value:  the attribute value
 *
 * Set (or reset) an attribute carried by a node.
 * The ns structure must be in scope, this is not checked
 *
 * Returns the attribute pointer.
 */
xmlAttrPtr xmlSetNsProp(xmlNodePtr node, xmlNsPtr ns, const xmlChar *name, const xmlChar *value)
    {
    xmlAttrPtr prop;

    if(ns && (ns->href == NULL))
        return (NULL);
    prop = xmlGetPropNodeInternal(node, name, (ns != NULL) ? ns->href : NULL, 0);
    if(prop != NULL)
        {
        /*
         * Modify the attribute's value.
         */
        if(prop->atype == XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID)
            {
            xmlRemoveID(node->doc, prop);
            prop->atype = XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID;
            }
        if(prop->children != NULL)
            xmlFreeNodeList(prop->children);
        prop->children = NULL;
        prop->last = NULL;
        prop->ns = ns;
        if(value != NULL)
            {
            xmlNodePtr tmp;

            if(!xmlCheckUTF8(value))
                {
                xmlTreeErr(XML_TREE_NOT_UTF8, (xmlNodePtr)node->doc,
                NULL);
            if (node->doc != NULL)
            node->doc->encoding = xmlStrdup(BAD_CAST "ISO-8859-1");
            }
        prop->children = xmlNewDocText(node->doc, value);
        prop->last = NULL;
        tmp = prop->children;
        while(tmp != NULL)
            {
            tmp->parent = (xmlNodePtr)prop;
            if(tmp->next == NULL)
                prop->last = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
            }
        }
    if(prop->atype == XML_ATTRIBUTE_ID)
        xmlAddID(NULL, node->doc, value, prop);
    return (prop);
    }
/*
 * No equal attr found; create a new one.
 */
return (xmlNewPropInternal(node, ns, name, value, 0));
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is what I need, because I want to change the href, but not a property. Href is not considered a property. Also I visited xmlsoft.org before, but there is no solution for my problem.

Comment: In the source code it seems that the namespace is intended as ns->href, check the edited answer

Comment: I checked this function, but this is not what I want, I want to change `ns->href`, but there is no function for that. As I understand it - the only way to do this is create new namespace, and call `xmlSetNs`, but I can't create default namespace, because it already exists in this node.

Comment: Ok, I realized that I could create new namespace without node. But now after `xmlNodeDump` I get grammar-tag at all without xmlns, it's strange.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
xmlSetNs(copied, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hang my answer off the title

> libxml2 ... /remove namespace

and I think it will also help with the general case of replacing a namespace.

To completely wipe all namespace info from a libxml2 doc, I used the following code:

```
// remove xmlns="..."
void remove_NsDef(xmlNodePtr node) {
    if (node->nsDef) {
        ::xmlFreeNsList(node->nsDef);
        node->nsDef = nullptr;
    }
}

void remove_ns_fully(xmlNodePtr node) {
    remove_NsDef(node);
    ::xmlSetNs(node, nullptr); // set NS empty for unprefixed XPath lookup
}

void remove_ns_fully_recursive(xmlNodePtr node) {
    remove_ns_fully(node);
    for (auto child = node->children; child != nullptr; child = child->next) {
        remove_ns_fully_recursive(child);
    }
}
```