# Libxml2 - Memory Leak Renaming Namespace Prefixes

Tags: c++, xml, xml-namespaces, libxml2

I'm working on renaming namespace prefixes in XML documents using Libxml2 for C. The code I have here is where the renaming takes place. It gets the job done but Valgrind is reporting a small memory leak from the original namespace ptr that was allocated via `xmlParseDocument(doc)`.

```
    xmlNsPtr def(xmlSearchNs(NULL, node, nsptr->prefix));
    const char* myPrefix = "foo";
    def->prefix = (xmlChar*) myPrefix;
```

Calling `xmlFreeNs(nsptr)` results in a SIGABRT from an invalid free.
Calling `free(nsptr)` has no affect.
Calling `xmlFreeNsList(nsptr)` or `delete(nsptr)` reduce the size of the memory leak... but segfault.

I have not found any examples of prefix manipulation with Libxml2, and the [API documentation for Libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html) does not offer a function for this, so I'm just about iterating through possibilities at this point. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Simply free `def->prefix` before reassigning.

Answer (score 1):

[Update] So after lots of trial and error, the solution I found which works is a combination of what [nwllnhof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956010/nwellnhof) described and a code snippet found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49356983/14358125) on changing/removing namespaces.

```
xmlNsPtr def(xmlSearchNs(NULL, node, nsptr->prefix));
xmlFree((void*) def->prefix);
def->prefix = xmlStrdup((const xmlChar*) "foo");
```